# Einsum slower than explicit Numpy implementation for n-mode tensor-matrix product

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement the n-mode tensor-matrix product (as defined by Kolda and Bader: https://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/pubs/pubfiles/SAND2007-6702.pdf) efficiently in Python using Numpy. The operation effectively gets down to (for matrix U, tensor X and axis/mode k):

1. Extract all vectors along axis k from X by collapsing all other axes.
2. Multiply these vectors on the left by U using standard matrix multiplication.
3. Insert the vectors again into the output tensor using the same shape, apart from X.shape[k], which is now equal to U.shape[0] (initially, X.shape[k] must be equal to U.shape[1], as a result of the matrix multiplication).

I've been using an explicit implementation for a while which performs all these steps separately:

1. Transpose the tensor to bring axis k to the front (in my full code I added an exception in case k == X.ndim - 1, in which case it's faster to leave it there and transpose all future operations, or at least in my application, but that's not relevant here).
2. Reshape the tensor to collapse all other axes.
3. Calculate the matrix multiplication.
4. Reshape the tensor to reconstruct all other axes.
5. Transpose the tensor back into the original order.

I would think this implementation creates a lot of unnecessary (big) arrays, so once I discovered np.einsum I thought this would speed things up considerably. However using the code below I got worse results:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

def mode_k_product(U, X, mode):
    transposition_order = list(range(X.ndim))
    transposition_order[mode] = 0
    transposition_order[0] = mode
    Y = np.transpose(X, transposition_order)
    transposed_ranks = list(Y.shape)
    Y = np.reshape(Y, (Y.shape[0], -1))
    Y = U @ Y
    transposed_ranks[0] = Y.shape[0]
    Y = np.reshape(Y, transposed_ranks)
    Y = np.transpose(Y, transposition_order)
    return Y

def einsum_product(U, X, mode):
    axes1 = list(range(X.ndim))
    axes1[mode] = X.ndim + 1
    axes2 = list(range(X.ndim))
    axes2[mode] = X.ndim
    return np.einsum(U, [X.ndim, X.ndim + 1], X, axes1, axes2, optimize=True)

def test_correctness():
    A = np.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
    for i in range(3):
        B = np.random.rand(6, A.shape[i])
        X = mode_k_product(B, A, i)
        Y = einsum_product(B, A, i)
        print(np.allclose(X, Y))

def test_time(method, amount):
    U = np.random.rand(256, 512)
    X = np.random.rand(512, 512, 256)
    start = time()
    for i in range(amount):
        method(U, X, 1)
    return (time() - start)/amount

def test_times():
    print("Explicit:", test_time(mode_k_product, 10))
    print("Einsum:", test_time(einsum_product, 10))

test_correctness()
test_times()
```

Timings for me:

Explicit: 3.9450525522232054

Einsum: 15.873924326896667

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? I know there are circumstances where storing intermediate results can decrease complexity (e.g. chained matrix multiplication), however in this case I can't think of any calculations that are being repeated. Is matrix multiplication so optimized that it removes the benefits of not transposing (which technically has a lower complexity)?

Comment: Following are the timings on my system (3.6.5, NumPy 1.14.3): `Explicit: 1.1669329166412354` and `Einsum: 1.553536319732666`

Comment: My timings are: `Explicit: 0.781634783744812
Einsum: 0.8676517248153687`
on Python 3.5  and NumPy 1.16.1. what NumPy version are you using?

Comment: In `k_product` the heavy lifting is in the `@` product.  The transpose and reshaping is virtually costless.  Depending on the shapes `einsum` optimize might end up using `matmul` as well.  So it's not surprising that the timings will be similar.

Comment: Thanks or your comments, looks like my software may be a bit outdated. I'm using Python 3.6.7 with Numpy 1.13.3. I'll see if I can update my Numpy installation. My computer is still drastically slower though, could this have something to do with hardware? I'm using an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz and both methods seem to use only one core.

Comment: The use of the `optimize` parameter in einsum has shifted quite a bit in recent `numpy` versions.  So yes, it would be good to get a recent version, and test a couple of alternatives.

Comment: I just updated Numpy to version 1.16.2 and it seems both methods are now multi-threaded ... new timings: `Explicit: 1.1844493389129638 Einsum: 1.2710027694702148`. And single-threaded: `Explicit: 1.461404013633728
Einsum: 1.5477246522903443`

So thanks a lot for that suggestion, that was something I should have done anyway ...

Comment: I get best `einsum` times with `optimize=False`.

Comment: Strange, with `optimize=False` I get `Einsum: 14.615312027931214
` ... In any case, thanks for all the answers, now that both methods are roughly equal for this test I can run them on real data with some extra operations and compare. :)

Comment: @Wout12345 Instead of adding RESOLVED we invite you to post an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Numpy, Einsum is only slightly slower than the explicit method, with or without multi-threading (see comments to my question).

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the subscripts style of using `einsum`, so worked out these equivalences:

```
In [194]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl',B0,A), einsum_product(B0,A,0))          
Out[194]: True
In [195]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,kjl->kil',B1,A), einsum_product(B1,A,1))          
Out[195]: True
In [196]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,klj->kli',B2,A), einsum_product(B2,A,2))          
Out[196]: True
```

With a `mode` parameter, your approach in `einsum_product` may be best.  But the equivalences help me visualize the calculation better, and may help others.

Timings should basically be the same.  There's an extra setup time in `einsum_product` that should disappear in larger dimensions.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it like this first, but my application may involve higher-dimensional tensors so I went ahead and wrote a more general one anyway for future use.